# Replace the old Email Addresses with new email in SSRS Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services

The company decided to change their domain name and no longer will accept the old email addresses. need toupdate the email address inside all of those subscriptions without going into each subscription and updating them.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE abc 

DECLARE @list TABLE 
  ( 
     id              INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
     oldemailaddress VARCHAR(100), 
     newemailaddress VARCHAR(100) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @list 
            (oldemailaddress, 
             newemailaddress) 
SELECT [global address], 
       [abc-address] 
FROM   [dbo].[abc-data final] 

--select * from @list 
DECLARE @OldEmailAddress VARCHAR(100), 
        @NewEmailAddress VARCHAR(100), 
        @totalRecords    INT, 
        @I               INT, 
        @SubscriptionID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT oldemailaddress, 
         newemailaddress 
  FROM   @list 

OPEN email_cursor 

FETCH next FROM email_cursor INTO @OldEmailAddress, @NewEmailAddress 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN TRANSACTION 

      UPDATE abc.dbo.subscription_email_test 
      SET    extensionsettings = CONVERT(NTEXT, Replace( 
                                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), extensionsettings) 
                                                , 
                                                    @OldEmailAddress, 
                                                       @NewEmailAddress)) 
      FROM   abc.dbo.subscription_email_test 
      WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), extensionsettings) LIKE 
                    '%' 
                                                           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100 
                    ), 
                    @OldEmailAddress 
                    ) 
                                                           + '%' 

      --rollback transaction 
      COMMIT TRANSACTION 

      PRINT 'Old: ' + @OldEmailAddress + ' New: ' 
            + @NewEmailAddress + 'SubscriptionID: ' 
            + Isnull(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), @SubscriptionID), 'NOT FOUND') 

      FETCH next FROM email_cursor INTO @OldEmailAddress, @NewEmailAddress 
  END 

CLOSE email_cursor 

USE abc 

DECLARE @list TABLE 
  ( 
     id              INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
     oldemailaddress VARCHAR(100), 
     newemailaddress VARCHAR(100) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @list 
            (oldemailaddress, 
             newemailaddress) 
SELECT [global address], 
       [abc-address] 
FROM   [dbo].[abc-data final] 

--select * from @list 
DECLARE @OldEmailAddress VARCHAR(100), 
        @NewEmailAddress VARCHAR(100), 
        @totalRecords    INT, 
        @I               INT, 
        @SubscriptionID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT oldemailaddress, 
         newemailaddress 
  FROM   @list 

OPEN email_cursor 

FETCH next FROM email_cursor INTO @OldEmailAddress, @NewEmailAddress 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN TRANSACTION 

      UPDATE abc.dbo.subscription_email_test 
      SET    extensionsettings = CONVERT(NTEXT, Replace( 
                                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), extensionsettings) 
                                                , 
                                                    @OldEmailAddress, 
                                                       @NewEmailAddress)) 
      FROM   abc.dbo.subscription_email_test 
      WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), extensionsettings) LIKE 
                    '%' 
                                                           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100 
                    ), 
                    @OldEmailAddress 
                    ) 
                                                           + '%' 
      COMMIT TRANSACTION 

      PRINT 'Old: ' + @OldEmailAddress + ' New: ' 
            + @NewEmailAddress + 'SubscriptionID: ' 
            + Isnull(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), @SubscriptionID), 'NOT FOUND') 

      FETCH next FROM email_cursor INTO @OldEmailAddress, @NewEmailAddress 
  END 

CLOSE email_cursor 
DEALLOCATE email_cursor ;


----------
```